# Undefined Javascript Error When AJAX Call Fails

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC controller being called by AJAX and returns JSON. If the call succeeds without error, I am returning a string message with the key "message". Likewise, if an exception is caught, I return a string error also with the key "message". I also return a HTTP error response.

In my Javascript, I output this "message" in an alert. The alert displays the message in the event of a successful call. If the call is unsuccessful, I get a Javascript error that "data is undefined".

1. Why is "data" accessible when successful but not when the call fails, and what correction do I need to make this work?
2. I am a newbie to AJAX calls with Spring so any general feedback/critique of my solution below is welcome and appreciated.

N.B. The alerts in the Javascript and the messages themselves are dummy implementations until I correctly provide user feedback by modifying the DOM.

The Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getMovieData", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> getMovieData(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> json, HttpServletResponse response) {

    String movieId = json.get("id").toString();

    Map<String, Object> rval = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    try {
        Movie movie = movieService.getMovieData(movieId);           
        rval.put("message", "You have succeeded");
        rval.put("movie", movie);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        rval.put("message", "You have an error - " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return rval;

}
```

The Javascipt

```
function getMovieData(data) {

    var request = $.ajax({

        type : 'POST',
        url : '<c:url value="/getMovieData" />',
        dataType : "json",
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data : data,

    });

    request.done(function(data) {
        alert("Success: " + data.message);          
        populateMovieFields(data.movie);
    });

    request.fail(function(xhr, status, error, data) {
        alert("status: " + status);
        alert("error: "  + error);
        alert("Fail: " + data.message); 
    });

}
```

Comment: fail can be triggered for many reasons other than your server response. First don't assume it is json in the fail callback. It could be caused by connection error, timeout etc. Need to do some type checking of what data is, if it even exists. Also fail can be triggered by a json parse error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON response is available inside the `jqXHR` object passed as the first parameter.

```
request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   alert("Fail: " + jqXHR.responseJSON.message); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm curious why this is the case. I'm guessing that the response object (in my case "data") is wrapped within the xhr object by either Spring or Tomcat in the even of an error? Is this the case?

Comment: Actually, the right parameters are `jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown`. The response is not directly injected to the `fail` handler as a param. I updated my answer to avoid confusion. You can check the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more info